# Menu-Navigation With Javascript on Main Landing Page. Troubles

Tags: javascript, html

I want to change the `HTML` link which is in `Javascript` on the thankyou page. I even tried changing the `HTML` links of all the respective pages on the thankyou page to `index.html/javascript:goTo(XXXX)` but it is not working.

How will I change the link so that I can link the thankyou page to the respective pages? By the way, both the index and thankyou pages use the same `HTML` template. The codes are shown here as following:

**index.html**

```
<div id="preloader"></div>

<div id="menu-wrap">

    <ul class="slimmenu">
        <li> 
            <a href="javascript:goTo('home');">home</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="javascript:goTo('about');">about us</a>
        </li>
        <li> 
            <a href="javascript:goTo('services');">What We Do</a>
        </li>
    </ul>

</div>
```

**thankyou.html**

```
<div id="preloader"></div>

<div id="menu-wrap"> 

    <ul class="slimmenu">
        <li> 
            <a href="javascript:goTo('home');">home</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="index2.html">about us</a>
        </li>
        <li> 
            <a href="index2.html">What We Do</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**Javascript function goTo**

```
function goTo(id){
        var obj = eval("colors."+id);

        $("body").css("background",obj.background);
        $("ul.slimmenu li a").css("color",obj.background);
        if(obj.index > currentIndex){
            $(".active").addClass("off");
            $(".active").transition({
                x : -100,
                opacity : 0,
                zIndex : 0
            },600);

            $("#"+currentId).removeClass("active");

            $("#"+id).addClass("active");
            $("#"+id).transition({
                perspective: '100px',
                rotate3d: '1,1,0,90deg'
            },0,function(){
                $("#"+id).removeClass("off");
                $("#"+id).transition({
                    rotate3d: '0,0,0,0deg',
                x : 0,
                    opacity : 1,
                    zIndex : 2
                },600);
            });
        }else if(obj.index < currentIndex){
            $(".active").addClass("off");
            $(".active").transition({
                x : 100,
                opacity : 0,
                zIndex : 0
            },600);
            $("#"+currentId).removeClass("active");


            $("#"+id).addClass("active");
            $("#"+id).transition({
                perspective: '100px',
                rotate3d: '1,1,0,-90deg'
            },0,function(){
                $("#"+id).removeClass("off");
                $("#"+id).transition({
                    rotate3d: '0,0,0,0deg',
                x : 0,
                    opacity : 1,
                    zIndex : 2
                },600);
            });
        }
        currentIndex = obj.index;
        currentId = id;

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just need to know which section to show in that page, you can try sending a hash value along like `index.html#home`. Then in index.html with javascript get the value of hash, e.g. `window.location.hash` and based on that show/hide the appropriate section.

Not sure if this is what your problem was, but I hope it helps give you some ideas.